# Exponential pdf interpretation

Tags: probability

I am looking at an exponential pdf in the context of interarrival times. The intensity is $2$ per unit of time. I plot the pdf of

$$f_{Y_1} (y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y}, y \geq 0$$

What is $y$ here, it is time, right?

If I plot this pdf, I get:

[image]

Which does not make much sense.

1. Should not pdf give as a result the probability? Do I need to use scale constant, to turn the output into probability?
2. Is the output of the pdf an interarrival time instead of the probability?
3. I need to sample interarrival times from this pdf. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software has computed $f$ at a small number of far apart points, turn joined them with lines. If you adjust the settings, you should get a smooth curve. The probability that $a\le y\le b$ is $\int_a^b f(y) dy$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates) for how to sample $Y$.

Comment: I did that before (the smooth curve). It is just a smoother curve.

Comment: I think $\lambda$ that I should have used in my equation is not $2$, but $1/2$

Comment: Well, with $2$ events per unit time the time between consecutive events has mean $1/\lambda=1/2$, so yes, you need $\lambda=2$. It's called a rate parameter.

Comment: k coo. So I can ignore the output from above. The probability is what you have defined it to be. And To sample I invert it, or just use the numpy's np.random.exponential :)

Comment: Give scipy.stats.exponential a look as well. That way, it can do more than just sample (which you do with scipy.stats.exponential.rvs).